# refactor ajax on click buttons with different class to same location

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a set of ajax calls that points to the same location with different classes per button.  The code is literally identical and works but I am thinking there should be a cleaner or better way to do this.

My code is as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
 $(document).on('click', '.passed', function(){
  let test_id = $(this).attr("id");
  let passed_id = 3;
   $.ajax({
    url:"testmanagement.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{test_id:test_id, passed_id:passed_id},
    success:function(data)
    {
      location.reload();
    }
   });
 });
    
 $(document).on('click', '.retest', function(){
  let test_id = $(this).attr("id");
  let retest_id = 4;
   $.ajax({
    url:"testmanagement.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{test_id:test_id, retest_id:retest_id},
    success:function(data)
    {
      location.reload();
    }
   });
 });
   
 $(document).on('click', '.proof', function(){
  let test_id = $(this).attr("id");
  let info_id = 5;
   $.ajax({
    url:"testmanagement.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{test_id:test_id,info_id:info_id},
    success:function(data)
    {
      location.reload();
    }
   });
 });
</script>
```

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest only this

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
     $(document).on('click', '.passed', function(){
      let test_id = $(this).attr("id");
      let passed_id = 3;
      sendData( {test_id:test_id, passed_id:passed_id});
     });
        
     $(document).on('click', '.retest', function(){
      let test_id = $(this).attr("id");
      let retest_id = 4;
     sendData( {test_id:test_id, retest_id:retest_id});
      });
       
     $(document).on('click', '.proof', function(){
      let test_id = $(this).attr("id");
      let info_id = 5;
     sendData({test_id:test_id,info_id:info_id});
       });

function sendData(data)
{
       $.ajax({
        url:"testmanagement.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:data,
        success:function(data)
        {
          location.reload();
        }
       });
}
    </script>
```